# How do I transfer my village to another ID on the same device?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm using a friend's Apple ID and playing COC from it. Now that I've created a new Apple ID for myself I want to transfer my COC account to my new Apple ID on the same device without losing my village.  How can I do this transfer?

Comment: Check out [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/329985/208941) answer and let me know

Answer (score 2):

First it needs to be connected to the Game Centre.

1. Open Clash of Clans on both of your iOS devices.
2. Open the in-game settings window on both devices.
3. Press the 'Link a device' button.
4. Select OLD DEVICE on the device you would like to move your village FROM.
5. Select NEW DEVICE on the device you would like to move your village TO.
6. Use the device code provided on your OLD DEVICE and enter it on your NEW DEVICE.

**Note:** Because this is the same method as transferring to a Google Play account, it means you will not be able to transfer to one.