# How to play the same village on two devices clash of clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

So my iPad was accidentally set up with the same Game Center account as my brothers when I set up my iPad. When I logged into clash of clans it loaded up his village and I tried deleting the app and logging out of Game Center. I created a new Game Center account and logged into clash of clans but his village still came up. I want to link my iPad with my village from my old android phone but I've already used link device and now all I can go on is my brothers village and we can't play the same village at the same time... Please help.

Comment: You have the device that has your own village?

Comment: Legally not allowed...

Answer (score 1):

You can not link the base more than once. This happened to me and I was out of luck, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

"Link a Device" option is not available since new update. But SuperCell have included "Super Cell ID"

- Choose the SupercellID in Settings, on your new device, it will be "Disconnected"
- Register/Login to Supercell ID by providing an email Id, and an One Time Password sent to your given email for verification, After verification, You CoC base will be linked to the SuperCell Id.
- Now you can use that id to connect\Link to another device.
- just use the same mail Id for the other device for the SupercellID to connect.

Answer (score 0):

To transfer a village from android to iOS:

1. First, open clash of clans and then clash of clans settings on both devices.
2. Choose "OLD DEVICE" from the options on the device with your account and "NEW DEVICE" on the other.
3. Choose "I want to link to another device" or "I want to link to an iPhone, iPad or iPod" using your phone. On the second device, type in the code that has been displayed.
4. Your devices should be linked.